# Can't get DrJava to run

Tags: java, ide

I keep getting this error message

"the registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.

The system cannot find the path specified"

I think it might have something to do with my environment variables or path or something.

Also I downloaded intelliJ and for that it keeps saying it can't find the main class

Comment: Post some screenshot in your question for the errors.

Comment: Did you remove a Java installation?

Comment: actually I think I got it to work